# Creating a hash table in C (Structures...)

Tags: c

I have a pointer of arrays,

```
NODE *hasht[T_SIZE]; /* My hash table */
```

But I want to put my hashtable into a structure like so, because I want to keep tally of things like size and so forth.

```
typedef struct {
    int curr_size;
} hashtable;
```

How can I implement what I have now, and put it within the structure so when I initialize a new instance of *hashtable, it creates it.

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here.  Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.:-)

Comment: 'I have a pointer of arrays', not an Array of pointers?

Comment: my mistake yes an array of pointers

Answer (score 0):

Well and why don't you do it?

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t curr_size;
    NODE **hashTable;
}hashtable;
```